# Responsive web form in drupal 7

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, drupal-webform

I am using drupal webform module for my theme http://apptreetechnologies.com/apptreetech/ but when i resize the window the webform text fields are  not resized accordingly.below is css

```
    input.webform-calendar {
    display: none;
    padding: 3px;
    vertical-align: top;
    }
    html.js input.webform-calendar {
    display: inline;
    }
    .webform-container-inline label {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 1em;
    }
    .webform-container-inline div, .webform-container-inline div.form-item {
     display: inline;
     enter code here}
   .webform-container-inline div.description {
    display: block;
    }
    .webform-container-inline div.messages {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    }
    .webform-container-inline div.ajax-progress-bar div {
    display: inherit;
    }
    .webform-client-form #edit-submit {
    background: url("../images/submit.png") no-repeat scroll 0 0 / 100% auto rgba(0,0,0,0);
    border: medium none;
    cursor: pointer;
    font-size: 0;
    height: 31px;
    line-height: 0;
    margin-left: 10%;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: -99999px;
    width: 35%;
    }
    .form-textarea-wrapper textarea {
    width: 58%;
    }
```

Comment: You need to add your codes which are not working. A jsfiddle would be better. Also, I just checked the link you shared, not all of your codes are responsive.

Comment: @CodeMonk can you please tell me changes

Comment: they are your codes so you will have to put them here for others to see what's wrong with it.

Comment: @CodeMonk please check i have updated code

Comment: where is your html @tarun ?

Comment: @CodeMonk hey please check my view gallery css to make it responsive